# How to use OAuth tokens to access Microsoft Graph using Azure Functions in the background?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a service that processes user's data in the Microsoft Graph in the background (later perhaps also access to Google Account). For that I need to authenticate the user using Oauth with their personal Microsoft Account e.g. in a Web application and I understand I would need Delegated Permission as there is no Company Administrator involved to grant access for all users at once. So far I'm only able to access the Graph in the Web App like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node). 
I'm now struggling on how to get which Auth data from that user in Azure Functions to be able to access his data without any further user interaction (e.g. in a nightly batch job). I have not found any sample showing how I could do that without the user actually calling the Function directly from her browser nor how to handle the refresh of these tokens within Azure Functions.
Therefore I'm wondering

- Which auth data do I have to store (presumably in a Azure Table Storage) for later use in Azure Functions?
- How to refresh expiring tokens in Azure Functions so that the user does not have to login all the time?

Comment: If you want to know how to call Microsoft graph  in Azure Function, please refer to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/06/27/using-microsoft-graph-in-an-azure-function/)

Comment: I read that article but unfortunately it does not give a clue on my two core questions.